# FFMPEG Add recording to this command

Tags: ffmpeg

Raspberry Pi IP camera on my network broadcasting to a web browser. I want to save 10 minutes long video clips. This is the line:

```
raspivid  -t -0 -w 1080 -h 720 -awb auto -fps 30 -b 1200000 -o - |ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i - -vcodec copy -an -f flv -metadata streamName=myStream tcp://0.0.0.0:6666&
```

Following a youtube tutorial I managed to watch my rpi ip camera on the browser but I want to record myself sleeping to detect any breath interruption.

```
raspivid  -t -0 -w 1080 -h 720 -awb auto -fps 30 -b 1200000 -o - |ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i - -vcodec copy -an -f flv -metadata streamName=myStream tcp://0.0.0.0:6666&
```

Works fine! I only want to add recording to a file 10 minutes videos (in chronological order if it's possible)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the segment muxer to save the recording in 10 minute segments.

`ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i - -c copy -an -f flv -metadata streamName=myStream tcp://0.0.0.0:6666 -c copy -an -f segment -segment_time 600 -reset_timestamps 1 vid%d.mp4`

This will generate, in addition to streaming, vid1.mp4, vid2.mp4, vid3.mp4...

Due to keyframe placement, segments may not be exactly 10 minutes long.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gyan, but maybe because I'm so dumb, I copy and paste your line and the Pi hung up!

Comment: Sorry! I was right about me been a dumb, I use your line without my original raspivid part... Works amazing... Thank you very much Gyan!

Answer (score 0):

Another way from @Gyan's suggestion, you can combine `segment` and `strftime` format to record files with file name as time that it starts recording like:

```
video_2019-08-04-12.00.00.flv
video_2019-08-04-12.10.00.flv
video_2019-08-04-12.20.00.flv
...
```

Following command below:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -i - -vcodec copy -an -f flv -metadata streamName=myStream tcp://0.0.0.0:6666 \ 
    -f segment -strftime 1 \ 
    -segment_time 00:10:00 \
    -segment_format flv \
    -an -vcodec copy \
    -reset_timestamps 1 \ 
    video_%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S.flv
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ThanPhan, but maybe because I'm so dumb, I copy and paste your line too and the Pi hung up!

Comment: Try to remove backslash '\' at the end of each line when you runt it